# Populate a RowSet with a sub-set of a ResultSet

Tags: java, jdbc, rowset

I have an application with works with a `java.sql.ResultSet`, and it needs to be able to export a user-specified subset of the `ResultSet` to XML. I'd like to use `javax.sql.rowset.WebRowSet` for this, like:

```
var resultset = connection.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT …");
var rowset = javax.sql.rowset.RowSetProvider.newFactory().createWebRowSet();
rowset.populate(resultset);
var writer = new StringWriter();
rowset.writeXml(writer);
return writer.toString();
```

However, this always serializes the entire `ResultSet` (which sometimes contains millions of rows). How can I serialize just a few rows of an open `ResultSet` to XML without re-executing the query?

Comment: There is `FilteredRowSetImpl` which extends `WebRowSet` and has possibility to add predicates for filtering

Comment: These are code samples of using [Filtered rowsets](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/filteredrowset.html) -and- [Web rowsets](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/webrowset.html). Both the row sets are sub-interfaces of `CachedRowSet`; and `FilteredRowSet` extends `WebRowSet` interface.